# Remove/distinct duplicates on listagg - oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, distinct, listagg

I'm using the oracle-xe 11g version and I have the below sql code that I aggregation the course code, but the output has duplicates.

```
SELECT
    b.alu_cpf            AS login,
    b.alu_nomeco         AS nome_completo,
    b.alu_emailpessoal   AS email,
    LISTAGG(d.cur1codigo, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY bdetcom.somentenumerosalfa(d.cur1codigo)) AS cod_curso,
    LISTAGG(d.cur1nomeco, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY bdetcom.somentenumerosalfa(d.cur1nomeco)) AS nome_curso,   
    TO_CHAR(b.alu_sexo, '9') AS sexo,
    a.alu_codigo AS matricula,
    b.alu_dtnascimento,  AS data_nascimento
FROM
    matricula_curr_dis              a
    INNER JOIN aluno                b ON b.alu_codigo = a.alu_codigo
    INNER JOIN dis01                c ON a.dis1codigo = c.dis1codigo
    INNER JOIN CUR01                d ON a.cur1codigo = d.cur1codigo
GROUP BY
    b.alu_cpf,
    b.alu_nomeco,
    b.alu_emailpessoal,
    a.alu_codigo,
    b.alu_sexo,
    b.alu_dtnascimento
ORDER BY
    nome_completo
```

Data:

```
login | nome | email  |      cod_curso
12345  fulano  xxxx     cod1, cod1, cod1, cod2
```

How I can distinct the cod_curso so it can look like this?

```
login | nome | email  |  cod_curso
12345  fulano  xxxx     cod1, cod2
```

Comment: You need to do it with a select that only gets the distinct values before you do the listagg. Newer versions of oracle have the feature built-in.

Comment: @JoeW, maybe this way:
```INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT dis01.dis1codigo 
        FROM dis01) c ON a.dis1codigo = c.dis1codigo
    
    INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT cur01.cur1codigo, cur01.cur1nomeco
        FROM cur01) d ON a.cur1codigo = d.cur1codigo```

Comment: Something like that should work. I didn't have time to write something up but was hoping hint could help.

Comment: The SQL even runs without error but does not make the distinction. I'll try another combination.